# Calculate z scores using zscore06

Tags: stata

How do I calculate z scores (WAZ, HAZ and WHZ)  using the `zscore06` package in Stata 12 on Windows 7? I checked `help zscore06` without much help.

Comment: The syntax in the help file seems clear. If you know what you want ("anthropometric z-scores using the 2006 WHO child growth standards"), it shouldn't be much of an issue to use. What's your specific problem? What code have you tried? Are we supposed to know what WAZ, HAZ and WHZ mean? What does "without much help" mean? See the _Asking_ section in http://stackoverflow.com/help.

Comment: The syntax is not that clear to me, please if its possible help me understand the syntax. WAZ -- weight for age z scores, HAZ - height for age Z scores , WHZ - weight for height z scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zscore06, a(nagem)  s(nsex) h(nheight) w(nweight)    male(1) female(2) o(n_oedema) oyes(1) ono(0)
/*
nagem - age
nsex-gender
nheight-height
nweight - weight
 male(1)//specify male label 
 female(2)//specify female label
n_oedema --oedema yes or no
oyes(1) //oedema yes
ono(0)  //oedema no
*/
```

The above command worked for me